# Mystery console error with IOHIDFamily

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

For one of my projects, this error message in Xcode's console happens every time I run a build in the iOS Simulator. It's been happening for over a year and I thought it would eventually go away with an update to Xcode. I've dereferenced and relinked all the Frameworks and I am not explicitly calling anything from the IOHIDFamily, whatever that is! It doesn't seem to affect my program execution but I would really like to figure out why it dumps all this every time.

```
2015-04-21 18:20:13.997 Vector-Z_beta[12370:1453236] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
2015-04-21 18:20:13.997 Vector-Z_beta[12370:1453236] Cannot find function pointer IOHIDLibFactory for factory 13AA9C44-6F1B-11D4-907C-0005028F18D5 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x78da9a80 </System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
2015-04-21 18:20:13.997 Vector-Z_beta[12370:1453236] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
2015-04-21 18:20:13.997 Vector-Z_beta[12370:1453236] Cannot find function pointer IOHIDLibFactory for factory 13AA9C44-6F1B-11D4-907C-0005028F18D5 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x78da9a80 </System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
2015-04-21 18:20:13.998 Vector-Z_beta[12370:1453236] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
2015-04-21 18:20:13.998 Vector-Z_beta[12370:1453236] Cannot find function pointer IOHIDLibFactory for factory 13AA9C44-6F1B-11D4-907C-0005028F18D5 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x78da9a80 </System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
2015-04-21 18:20:13.998 Vector-Z_beta[12370:1453236] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
2015-04-21 18:20:13.998 Vector-Z_beta[12370:1453236] Cannot find function pointer IOHIDLibFactory for factory 13AA9C44-6F1B-11D4-907C-0005028F18D5 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x78da9a80 </System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
```

Comment: I get the same, did you resolve this? I have tried all the (relevant) suggestions below to no avail. I'm using XCode 7.1 to build an app with Swift

Comment: I second that and will start a bounty because this is bugging me

Comment: I'm using XCode 7.1.1 too, and i'm trying to build an app with objective c

Comment: Any resolve to this. I have an app that used to work and not it doesn't and I get these errors.

Comment: Still occurring for me with XCode 7.2

Answer (score 74, accepted):

When deploying to a real iOS device you are building for an ARM architecture, when deploying to the iOS simulator you are building for an x386 architecture.

In the latter case your app links with mach-o files present on your Mac (unless as someone suggested you only link with SDK assemblies, not native Mac ones, but this will really slow down your build and isn’t an available option anymore in recent Xcode versions I believe).

Apparently, one of these mach-o files - the IOHIDFamily extension one, which seems to be linked if GameKit.framework is linked as a library - is not specifically built for the iOS simulator. Hence, the message.
As I understand this is a confirmed Apple bug and will be fixed by Apple at some point.

It is an issue with the iOS simulator only and can be safely ignored.

Comment: Add ons to the answer, build and run you app using real device and those annoying error will not present.

Comment: *It is an issue with the iOS simulator only and can be safely ignored.* - also occurs on the Apple TV tvOS simulator. Great answer. Thank you!

Comment: Xcode 7.3 and still not fixed. How does such an obvious bug not get addressed in a year? Do so few people out there use GameKit??

Answer (score 5):

Vinnie posted this solution

> try setting the IOS Build Options: Linker options to "Link SDK assemblies only", fixed it for me

here:
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/24656/error-running-app-after-upgrading-xamarin

Comment: I'm using Xcode 6.3, and that's not an option I have on the build target.

Comment: I can not find this option

Comment: This is a **Xamarin Studio** solution. Select your **product.iOS**, `Project` > `product.iOS Options` > `Build` > `iOS Build` > `Linker Behavior` > `Link Framework SDKs Only` > `OK`. Then `Clean All` and rebuild.

Answer (score 4):

Disabling Game Center capabilities remove these messages for me. On your Project, select the *Desired target* and go to *Capabilities*.

Comment: I'm using Game Center in my app, so not really an option here.

Comment: Same things for me. I disabled Game Center on the early stage of development but now I need it so I have to face these warnings.

Answer (score 0):

On new Xcode 7.2 these messages do not display anymore.

But I have new messages related to *SpriteKit* :
`CUICatalog: Invalid Request: requesting subtype without specifying idiom`

[CUICatalog: Invalid Request: requesting subtype without specifying idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33686413/540780)

Comment: As I wrote "I have" meaning in my case.Your case maybe different.

Comment: Funny enough, but I have both these problems now. Both are issues with the iOS 9 SDK from what I've read on the official Apple Dev forums.

Answer (score -2):

When I encountered this problem in iOS code, it was because two of my classes contained an import Foundation.  New File was defaulting to OS X / Source / Swift file and I hadn't noticed.

Removing those imports eliminated the problem.

Comment: thanks, but I only have one line that reads `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` (in my prefix header file) and it has the iOS framework path.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this "New File was defaulting to OS X / Source / Swift file". I don't understand. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm.  At this time, neither do I.  Both iOS and OSX Source choice (now?) give import Foundation.  I do know, that for the problem I was seeing, at that time, eliminating the import Foundation, or replacing Foundation with UIKit in the swift file's import resolved the problem.

Answer (score -2):

I solved this issue by going on GENERAL tab and uncheck **Requires Full Screen** option to disable iPad multitasking. But you can get validation errors if multitasking is not handled properly!

[image: Requires Full Screen]

Comment: Thanks but this problem predates iPad multitasking, and I don't have it checked anyway.