# Xcode update - impossible to debug

Tags: ios, xcode

The recent Xcode update has completely annihilated my app. To take things further, debugging any issues is impossible because sometimes it works correctly, and sometimes it doesn't.

For example: sometimes when I run my app, the textures and labels will load properly. Other times, one will load in front of the other. Same goes with labels.

All I can gather from that is that it is not a problem with my code, but a problem with the update. I did the syntax changes that they suggested when I first installed the program but to no avail.

The only hints I have are some strangle console messages I get after running the app:

> Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:
>   dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib,
>   262): no suitable image found.
>   Did find:
>       /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:
>   mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
>
> Cannot find function pointer IOHIDLibFactory for factory 13AA9C44-6F1B-11D4-907C-0005028F18D5 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn
>   0x7ffe99729c20
>   
>   (bundle, not loaded)

I have researched these and apparently they are harmless error messages.

My question is: how can I get my textures to render properly again? Why is Xcode reading it in a different order each time?

Comment: Try deleting the derived data for your project.  From the *Window* menu, *Projects*, select your project name on the left, and then click the little arrow inside the circle icon next to the derived data path; a Finder window opens.  Close Xcode, then delete the folders for all your projects.  Then relaunch xcode.

Comment: @i_am_jorf I did this and it still did not fix the problem. I did what you said, and I also just used the "Delete derived data" thing that's right next to the initial window that comes up. No luck. Also, as soon as I delete derived data, more springs up.

Comment: What technologies are you using? SpriteKit? If so, have you tried adjusting zPosition?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785320/mystery-console-error-with-iohidfamily