# CUICatalog: Invalid Request: requesting subtype without specifying idiom objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, sprite-kit, scale

I as you read in the title i got this error. what i think is interesting, that using NSLog using ipad it shows up as ipad, but doesnt use size for ipad in some places, but not in all for example:

```
#define IS_IPAD() (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
--------------------
      ball = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ball"];
      if(IS_IPAD()){
      ball.xScale = 0.4; // this works fine and i can change scale, if i want
      ball.yScale = 0.4;    
      }else{
      ball.xScale = 0.2;
      ball.yScale = 0.2;
  }
  --------------
        sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"board"];
        if(IS_IPAD()){
    NSLog(@"is ipad") // says it is
            sprite.xScale = 0.5; //doesnt work
            sprite.yScale = 0.7; //
        }else{
            sprite.xScale = 0.3; // takes this insted
            sprite.yScale = 0.5;
        }
```

Comment: Do you have GameCenter enabled? If so, try disabling it and see if you still get the error message. If so, it might be an apple bug that happens only on the simulator - trying it on a real device should work as expected.

Comment: This may relate to your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33686413/cuicatalog-invalid-request-requesting-subtype-without-specifying-idiom

Comment: @Andriko13 thank you for your response, before I post this, ī seen that post you posted, it dosn't related to my post. But I got question about GameCenter, I don't use it, but how can i disable it, iam new to programming.