# Sprite Image Not Loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, ios9.1

I am working on a Sprite Kit Game. Things were working fine until out of nowhere, Xcode decided to stop loading a particular sprite image and return this in the Console Log:

```
Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
2015-11-25 15:26:07.435 Project3[5843:800423] Cannot find function pointer IOHIDLibFactory for factory 13AA9C44-6F1B-11D4-907C-0005028F18D5 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7fba686b5a50 </System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
2015-11-25 15:26:07.435 Project3[5843:800423] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
2015-11-25 15:26:07.436 Project3[5843:800423] Cannot find function pointer IOHIDLibFactory for factory 13AA9C44-6F1B-11D4-907C-0005028F18D5 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7fba686b5a50 </System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
2015-11-25 15:26:07.436 Project3[5843:800423] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
2015-11-25 15:26:07.436 Project3[5843:800423] Cannot find function pointer IOHIDLibFactory for factory 13AA9C44-6F1B-11D4-907C-0005028F18D5 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7fba686b5a50 </System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
```

The code I used to add the image was:

```
self.superball = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"sbstore2.png"];
    self.superball.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)-200,CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    [self addChild:self.superball];
```

What should I do to resolve this error? I'm using Xcode 7.1.1, and this was first noticed after I upgraded to this.

Comment: did you try cleaning the project?

Comment: also,  I do not think you should be including the extension with ImageNamed

Comment: Cleaning the project doesn't work. And I want the sprite to be an image, so is there another way to make the sprite node an image without the spriteNodeWithImageNamed extension?

Comment: no use `[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"sbstore2"];`

Comment: Doesn't work. Is it a bug with Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is a bug. As KnightOfDragon said you shouldn't include extention then using `ImageNamed`, and also i recommend to use `Clean`

```
self.superBall = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"sbstore2"];
```

Instead of using initializer above you can just set texture of your node.

```
self.superBall.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"sbstore2"];
```

Or even runnig action to change texture.

```
[self.superBall runAction:[SKAction setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"sbstore2"]]];
```

If none of this work, you should double check is your image name is correct.
If you are adding just by dragging to project make sure you check `add to targets` and `Destination: copy items if needed`

Also here is more info about these errors: [Mystery console error with IOHIDFamily](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29785320/4078517)

Comment: It seems to work now. Thanks! Although I have used extensions in my code since Xcode 5, and it has worked fine then. Why shouldn't extensions be used?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW10 On iOS 4 and later, if the file is in PNG format, it is not necessary to specify the .PNG filename extension. Prior to iOS 4, you must specify the filename extension.

Comment: @master248 you can use extension, but you do not have to.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. The console is still returning the errors, but the image appears now. It's possible that it was just misplaced because I also changed its position. I looked into the Mystery console error with IOHIDFamily question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785320/mystery-console-error-with-iohidfamily before coming here though.

Comment: In my older project i have it too, it do not make any difference, i even submitted that app and it was aproved.